# Access localhost site on mobile devices within the same local network

Tags: apache, nginx, networking, web, webserver

Right now, I'm running my site on my Mac OS X locally via Apache.

I'm trying to reproduce a bug that only happen on iPhone Safari. I'm trying to avoid keep pushing the code to the staging server, pull, and then, test on my phone.

Is there a way to access my local site via my phone? via some kind of IP address?

Answer (score 0):

1. make phone connect to the same WIFI as MAC OSX
2. run the server on the non-localhost address (LAN DHCP allocated), noted as SRV_IP
3. access the SRV_IP from your phone

Comment: That is not working, since I used vhost with my Apache settings.

Comment: run a proxy in your MAC OS, and modify the hosts to map the vhost name to your local address